# how can we replace first character of a string in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

```
declare @test varchar(50) ='000000000000000000000000000000000050', @firstletter varchar (50)='T'
```

How can I replace THE first letter of @test and replace it with @firstletter  value

My output is `T00000000000000000000000000000000050`

Comment: you said first LETTER, not digit, however, you are replacing the first 0. Did you mean first CHARACTER of @test? please clarify

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - tag correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You listed TWO SQL databases, but fortunately the syntax would be the same

```
select @firstletter + substring( @test, 2, length( @test ) -1 )
```

But you would need to trap / test for conditions where @Test is less than 2 characters, but we dont know realization of your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then another way of doing this is using `stuff` to place the `@firstletter` at the beginning like below:

```
select STUFF(@test,1,1,@firstletter)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
SELECT @firstletter + SUBSTRING(@test, 2, LEN(@test) - 1)
```